# See values of temporaries in Visual Studio

Tags: c++, visual-studio

My C++ program runs into an uncought exception that looks something like

```cpp
throw std::runtime_error("failed with error " + std::to_string(getError()));
```

The debugger pauses the program at this line. Due to language rules a `std::runtime_error` with content *"failed with error -1"* must be created before the exception is thrown, so I know there is a temporary object of type `std::runtime_error` somewhere, except I am unsure about the number at the end. How can I see that object/string with the debugger? It shows me all the named local variables, but not the unnamed ones. Changing the code to give a name to the temporary, recompiling and reproducing the error gets quite time consuming after a while and is not feasible with rare errors.

I am currently using Visual Studio Express 2013 for desktop under Windows 7 and I would be willing to switch to an alternative such as Visual Studio 2015 CTP.

Comment: So, `getError()` returned `-1`. What else do you want to see?

Comment: @Lingxi I don't know that it returns -1. Maybe it returns 42. I cannot see the string, it was an example.

Comment: Then, you could just catch the exception and do `std::cout << e.what()` or something like that.

Comment: @Lingxi If I do that I see the exception text, but no local variables and no stack trace.

Answer (score 3):

Set breakpoint on this line. When program stops, hit `F11` (Step into), to enter the constructor of `std::runtime_error`. There, string will be available on `Autos` tab, because it will come as parameter.

Comment: Not bad. Still requires a restart, but does save me from recompiling.